# "git clean" command in IntelliJ Git GUI

Tags: git, jetbrains-ide

Do someone know how to use the "git clean" command in IntelliJ Git GUI?

I know it is possible if I use Terminal, but I want to use "git clean" command from GUI.

Comment: They don't say a word about it in the [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-git-integration.html). So I think you can't do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has a single command equivalent but you could open the "local changes" pane and delete all the untracked files.